# Can I wipe a Samsung 850 Evo SSD by plugging it into another computer through an enclosure and using erase software?

Tags: ssd, sata, privacy, secure-erase

I'm soon sending my computer to a repair shop and I want to wipe my SSD first before sending it in. I detatched the 850 Evo SSD from my computer and was wondering if I could connect it to a laptop through an enclosure [like this one](https://www.walmart.com/ip/StarTech-2-5-USB-3-0-External-SATA-III-SSD-Hard-Drive-Enclosure/29016166?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222227019623545&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=40881029312&wl4=pla-78811134152&wl5=9033255&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=29016166&wl13=&veh=sem&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI4427ys2W3wIV9h-tBh00IQLtEAQYBiABEgKts_D_BwE) and using software to wipe off / secure erase the data. I don't have another PC to plug my SSD in, so I have to rely on this method.

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: Do you even need to send the drive in?  For example, if the system's video was out or some other issue, having or not having a hard drive wouldn't really matter.  The shop should be able to boot and run diagnostics from an external CD or USB drive.

Comment: If you're concerned about wiping it, why don't you just reinstall the OS on the SSD? Do you plan on saving any of the data that is currently on the SSD?

Comment: If there's any chance that the issue is on the SSD, it may make it impossible to diagnose if you erase it.  For example, if it's a driver or corruption issue.  You might be better off off-loading your personal files and then deleting them from the SSD.  If the computer is basically operational, you wouldn't need to plug it into another computer for that.

Comment: @fixer1234 My computer isn't operational at all, and will not show any signs of life. Is it possible to boot from an SSD enclosure on my laptop if I have Windows To Go?

Comment: If it has no sign of life when you power it on--no indicator lights or fans--the problem may be the power supply.  But there could also be other issues.  If there are no signs of life, you wouldn't be able to boot from any device.  In that case, you would need to clean up the SSD on another computer (and you can use an external enclosure with a laptop for that).  There may be more than one problem, so it would still be a good idea to only remove your personal files and let the tech check everything and ensure that everything is working.

Comment: @AdamLee If you  want to securely wipe the drive, please read my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can wipe your SSD by attaching the drive in a USB enclosure to another computer.

However, there is more to consider here:

Due to the nature of how modern SSDs work, a generic wiping utility will ***not*** necessarily erase all your data.  Fragments of your data can be left, albeit in an unreadable state.  Typically, this is "good enough."

However, if you want to properly and *securely* wipe your SSD clean, leaving no remnants, you *must* use the SSD's manufacturer specific SSD wiping utility.  For Samsung, it is the [Samsung Magician Software](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can through Windows, Linux, or other methods. Format the drive by connecting it as an external HDD via USB or Firewire. Using Windows to format usually has an option to not format it quickly but rather replace the data with all zeros to truly erase the data both through GUI and command-line. Linux distros also have this capability, especially if your using linux through a Live USB while the SSD is actively in your computer. If your using linux, there are command-line tools like fdisk, and parted, and GUI tools like Gparted.

Comment: Sorry about that fixer1234. If you look above I have appropriately edited my answer to provide more detail.