# How do I securely erase an SSD that is already formatted?

Tags: macos, ssd, security, encryption

I'm trying to sell my 2015 MacBook Pro, but first I need to securely erase my SSD.

All the help I find online only seems to talk about how to do a cryptographic erase on an SSD. Writing zeros to every bit once or multiple times lowers the lifespan of the SSD, and my MacBook Pro doesn't seem to let me do that anyway. The trouble is, I've already formatted the drive, and I'm worried that reinstalling macOS and enabling FileVault to encrypt my files won't actually encrypt the already "deleted" files from before I formatted the drive.

What would I need to do to make be reasonably sure that my data can't be recovered easily by the next owner?

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/1382487/can-i-wipe-a-samsung-850-evo-ssd-by-plugging-it-into-another-computer-through-an/1382539#1382539

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this doesn't answer my question. First, my SDD is not SATA. Second, I've already formatted the drive.

Comment: Who's the SSD manufacturer, what's the model? Already formatting it is irrelevant if the goal is to securely erase it - you won't know if it was formatted before or not, that's the point.

Comment: Ah my problem was that I didn't understand that the MacOS FileVault feature is essentially the same thing as full disk encryption. I had thought that it was just going to encrypt the data that was there since I reinstalled. This article helped me out. http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/22/secure-erase-mac-ssd-drive-recovery-mode/

Comment: My SSD manufacturer is Apple, by the way.